# Troubles with creating RAID1 array on VM Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: virtualbox, raid

I'm trying to create RAID 1 - array on VM Ubuntu 15.04 with two disks: **sda** and **sdb**. First disk already had partition table, so i created sections for the second disk using `fdisk /dev/sdb`:

[image: Screen Shot]

Then i format sdb using `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` and mount it using `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /usr/data`

Now I'm trying to create RAID 1 array using `mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sda1`. But I get an error: cannot open/use /dev/sdb1 : "Device or resource busy".

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: wait you want to raid /dev/sda and /dev/sdb right.

Comment: @Neil yes, am i choose wrong disks?

Comment: yep you will need to add another disk to your VM

Comment: But i need to create RAID1 with the disk on which i installed Ubuntu and new disc. It is possible?

Comment: If you wanting to create a RAID with the Operating system on it. You need to Do a Hardware RAID not a software raid.

Comment: Ok,i'll try it,thank you.Should i delete my question?

Comment: no. the best thing you could do is mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two blank drives with no partitions on them  to do a RAID

example /dev/sdb and /dev/sdd have no partitions on them.

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdd
```

that will create `/dev/md0` and then you can create partitions on `/dev/md0` only.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all wrong.
First: you need to create md0 device.
Second: you format your /dev/md0 to ext4.
Third: mount your device to /use/data